# WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://192.168.0.109:11311] host is not set to this machine

Tags: turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,i am trying to use turtlebot as website [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot). when i have done [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup). and i can  check that TurtleBot laptop can get data from ROS node running on workstation. and the  problem is when i run "roscore"in my workstation , i get

```
waring:WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://192.168.0.109:11311] host is not set to this machine.
```

and http://192.168.0.109 is my turtlebot ip.and my workstation ip is 192.168.0.103.  when i run

```
$ rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard&
```

my dashboard  buttons remain all grey. what's matter ?thank s a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48792/warning:-ros_master_uri-%5Bhttp://192.168.0.109:11311%5D-host-is-not-set-to-this-machine/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can only have one roscore active (and configured) at a time. In case of the turtlebot the roscore should always run on the turtlebot itself to keep latencies and actual network usage low.

If you wanted to use a roscore on your workstation to work, while the turtlebot isn't running, you have to change your `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the name or IP of your workstation.

Dont forget to source the .bashrc again after the change, or restart your open consoles.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2